# Is there a closed form expression for $E(X e^{-\mu \sqrt{X}})$, where $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $\mu >0$?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Is there any closed form expression for $E(X e^{- \mu \sqrt{X}})$, where $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $\mu >0$? If not, is there any tight upper bound for this quantity? Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: "tight upper bound" for which regime?  E.g., $\lambda\to \infty$ and/or $\mu \to \infty$, etc....

Comment: ideally for all possible $\lambda$ and $\mu$...but for me the more interesting regime would be $\mu > \lambda$, but I am not sure if this would help in finding a tight upper bound.

Comment: Asking for too good asymptotics on too much of a multidimensional domain makes it much harder to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split ?

$$E(Xe^{-\mu\sqrt{X}})=E(Xe^{-\sqrt{\mu^2X}})\leq E(Xe^{-\mu^2X}\mathbf{1}_{\mu^2X\leq 1})+E(X\mathbf{1}_{\mu^2X\geq 1})$$